# Dynamic PayPal Integration

Tags: paypal, .net-3.5

I am developing software that will allow a user to create forms based on draggable controls, in the fashion of, say, an online survey. This is how it's supposed to go:

- *User A* makes a form.
- *User A* sends said form to *User B*.
- *User B* fills out and submits the form.

Here's what I need: I have a page that allows *User A* to set up a PayPal payment for each entry into a form. This would require *User B* to successfully pay with PayPal before he could submit his entry. I do not want *User A* to have to do anything more than specify the amount/entry and his PayPal email.

My problem comes in after *User B* has paid for the entry and decides to close the tab instead of returning to the store. This doesn't allow me to submit the form. How can I create a full-proof method to assure this doesn't happen?

Things to keep in mind: Assume *User A* does not have IPN/Auto-Return enabled and potentially isn't a business account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found that if you use the notify_url html variable, the merchant does not need to enable IPN. Therefore allowing me to tell PayPal to always post to my server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PayPal standard there is no fool-proof way to do this since the user leaves your site to do the transaction.  PayPal has other offerings that claim to allow this, but they may expose you to PCI-DSS compliance issues.

A better choice would be to use a system like Stripe, where the user never really leaves your site.

Comment: I am providing Stripe as the preferred option, but a few of my clients have requested PayPal as an option as well.

Comment: Then you just have to live with them not coming back.  That's how PayPal standard works.

Comment: Is there a way that I could force PayPal to send an IPN message if the Merchant doesn't have it enabled? If so, then I could possible create a table that holds the data until I get it.